# Can you attach a sprite renderer to a child of a main game object and still have the animator access functions from the main object for events?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, sprite

When creating a player or enemy in unity, I've learnt that it's best practise to attach the sprite renderer to a child game object so that you can easily reposition the sprite. However, doing this means that the animator also needs to be attached to the child game object, which means you don't have any access to the functions from the parent game object for animation events . Does anyone know a way around this?

I tried putting the animator on the parent object, but then it said the sprite renderer component was missing so I believe they need to be on the same object.

Comment: Use `GetComponent` or have a reference to the child you set in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried putting the animator on the parent object, but then it said the sprite renderer component was missing so I believe they need to be on the same object.

No! What happened is you moved the animator root so the original property paths stored in your animation clip is invalid now.

The property paths are basically stored via the objects names.

What previously was e.g. (don't know the exact form of the property paths)

```
/Sprite/SomeProperty
```

would now need to be something like

```
YourSpriteObject/Sprite/SomeProperty
```

but since the animation still uses the first one and there is no `Sprite` component on your parent object it is invalid and displays as missing.

You will have to redo your animations or write an editor script for automatically changing all animation paths accordingly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686007/how-can-i-rename-my-creatures-models-hierarchy-without-breaking-animations) I once did something similar for renaming animated objects. You could probably write a similar thing for moving the animator component to a different object in the hierarchy

---

Alternatively expose the methods on your child object, and then forward them to trigger stuff on the parent via

```
transform.parent.GetComponent<YourParentClass>().YourMethod();
```

which of course I would either cache once or assign via the Inspector