# Avoiding hardcoded values with Animator triggers Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any recommended way for avoiding hard-coded values when updating triggers of a Unity Animator?

Currently I'm resorting to hard-coded variables, essentially copying their name from the Animator editor, and then calling them like so:

```
animator.SetBool("PurchaseAvailable", isUnlockPossible);
```

The problem with that, is that the name of the trigger might change, or be completely removed at one point, and then I'd only find about a problem on runtime, or even worse, in production.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about Hashing Strings into Ints and using?.. int Purchase = Animator.StringToHash("PurchaseAvailable");

Comment: @SelvarajBalakrishnan That wouldn't solve anything since a different name results in a different hash. He'd be using a wrong int instead of a string, but his problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned there isn't something built-in for this but you can use custom editor scripting to achieve something like it.

For instance you could have a custom property type with a custom editor that pulls the `Animator.parameters`, filter on a specific type and show a dropdown with the names.

Then on runtime cache the `Aniamtor.StringToHash`.

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class AnimatorParameter
{
    [SerializeField]
    private RuntimeAnimatorController animator;

    [SerializeField]
    private AnimatorControllerParameterType type;

    [SerializeField]
    private string name;

    private int? hash;

    public AnimatorControllerParameterType Type => type;
    public string Name => name;
    public RuntimeAnimatorController RuntimeAnimatorController;

    public int Hash
    {
        get
        {
            if (hash == null)
            {
                hash = Animator.StringToHash(name);
            }

            return hash.Value;
        }
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(AnimatorParameter))]
    private class AnimatorParameterDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2;
        }

        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            using (new EditorGUI.PropertyScope(position, label, property))
            {
                position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, label);

                var controllerRect = position;
                controllerRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                position.y += controllerRect.height;

                var controllerProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(animator));

                using (var change = new EditorGUI.ChangeCheckScope())
                {
                    EditorGUI.PropertyField(controllerRect, controllerProperty, GUIContent.none);

                    if (!controllerProperty.objectReferenceValue)
                    {
                        var infoRect = position;
                        infoRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                        EditorGUI.HelpBox(infoRect, "No animator referenced!", MessageType.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var typeRect = position;
                        typeRect.width = 80;
                        typeRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                        position.x += typeRect.width;

                        var nameRect = position;
                        nameRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                        nameRect.width -= typeRect.width;

                        var typeProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(type));

                        EditorGUI.PropertyField(typeRect, typeProperty, GUIContent.none);

                        var options = ((AnimatorController)controllerProperty.objectReferenceValue).parameters
                            .Where(p => p.type == typeProperty.GetEnumValue<AnimatorControllerParameterType>())
                            .Select(p => p.name)
                            .ToList();

                        var nameProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(name));
                        var currentIndex = options.IndexOf(nameProperty.stringValue);

                        var newIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(nameRect, currentIndex, options.ToArray());

                        nameProperty.stringValue = newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < options.Count ? options[newIndex] : "";
                    }

                    if (change.changed)
                    {
                        var target = (AnimatorParameter)fieldInfo.GetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject);
                        target.hash = null;
                        fieldInfo.SetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject, target);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

To make things a bit easier you could even add some extension methods like e.g.

```csharp
public static class AnimatorExtensions
{
    public static void SetFloat(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter, float value)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Float)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Float!");
        }

        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        animator.SetFloat(animatorParameter.Hash, value);
    }

    public static void SetInteger(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter, int value)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Int)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Int!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        animator.SetInteger(animatorParameter.Hash, value);
    }

    public static void SetBool(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter, bool value)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Bool!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        animator.SetBool(animatorParameter.Hash, value);
    }

    public static void SetTrigger(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Trigger!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        animator.SetTrigger(animatorParameter.Hash);
    }

    public static void ResetTrigger(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Trigger!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        animator.ResetTrigger(animatorParameter.Hash);
    }

    public static float GetFloat(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Float)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Float!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        return animator.GetFloat(animatorParameter.Hash);
    }

    public static int GetInteger(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Int)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Integer!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        return animator.GetInteger(animatorParameter.Hash);
    }

    public static bool GetBool(this Animator animator, AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        if (animatorParameter.Type != AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given parameter is not of type Bool!");
        }
        
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController != animatorParameter.RuntimeAnimatorController)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AnimatorControllers do not match!");
        }

        return animator.GetBool(animatorParameter.Hash);
    }
}
```

Here is a little demo how this would look like right now (can probably be improved)

```csharp
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    public AnimatorParameter animatorParameter;

    [ContextMenu(nameof(Apply))]
    public void Apply()
    {
        switch (animatorParameter.Type)
        {
            case AnimatorControllerParameterType.Float:
                animator.SetFloat(animatorParameter, Random.value);
                break;
            case AnimatorControllerParameterType.Int:
                animator.SetInteger(animatorParameter, Random.Range(0, 5));
                break;
            case AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool:
                animator.SetBool(animatorParameter, !animator.GetBool(animatorParameter));
                break;
            case AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger:
                animator.SetTrigger(animatorParameter);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

> The problem with that, is that the name of the trigger might change, or be completely removed at one point, and then I'd only find about a problem on runtime, or even worse, in production.

This same issue will of course still remain. Unfortunately a lot of things within the animation (and other) system(s) are string based (even e.g. [renaming/re-arranging of objects within the hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686007/how-can-i-rename-my-creatures-models-hierarchy-without-breaking-animations) is an issue). You *could* probably implement some wrappers around it and instead of directly remove/rename triggers etc only go through your custom code and basically inform/validate each and every instance of `AnimatorParameter`, update their values and reserialize their assets. This will get quite complex though and might not be worth the efforts.

You could in your tests e.g. have a simple validation like

```csharp
public static class AnimatorParameterExtensions
{
    public static void Validate(this AnimatorParameter animatorParameter)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(animatorParameter);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, (bool)animatorParameter.Animator);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(animatorParameter.Name));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, animatorParameter.Animator.parameters.Where(p => p.type == animatorParameter.Type).Any(p => p.name == animatorParameter.Name));
    }
}
```

I would actually like to see them implement something like e.g. in the new Input System where your entire custom input actions get generated into c# classes so if you rename them you immediately get a bunch of errors as well.

You could actually try and implement something similar - I'm not a code-generation expert but maybe this gives you a good starting point

```csharp
public static class AnimatorFancyCodeGenerator
{
    private const string className  = nameof(AnimatorFancyCodeGenerator);

    [MenuItem("Tools/Generate Animator Parameters Code")]
    private static void Generate()
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder
            .Append("using System;\n")
            .Append("using UnityEngine;\n\n")
            .Append("public class ").Append(className).Append("Result\n")
            .Append("{\n");

        var controllers = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + nameof(AnimatorController));
        foreach (var guid in controllers)
        {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            var controller = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<AnimatorController>(path);

            stringBuilder.Append($"    public class {controller.name.Replace(" ", "")}").Append("{\n");

            foreach (var parameter in controller.parameters)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append($"        private static int? _{parameter.type}_{parameter.name.Replace(" ", "")};\n")
                    .Append($"        public static int {parameter.type}_{parameter.name.Replace(" ", "")}\n")
                    .Append("        { get{\n")
                    .Append($"            if(_{parameter.type}_{parameter.name.Replace(" ", "")} == null)\n")
                    .Append("            {\n")
                    .Append($"                _{parameter.type}_{parameter.name.Replace(" ", "")} = Animator.StringToHash(\"{parameter.name}\");\n")
                    .Append("            }\n")
                    .Append($"            return _{parameter.type}_{parameter.name.Replace(" ", "")}.Value;")
                    .Append("       }}\n");
            }

            stringBuilder.Append("}\n");
        }

        stringBuilder.Append("}");

        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/" + className + "Result.cs", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString()));
        
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Which would then generate all your controllers into a class (for me reformatted it looks like e.g.)

```csharp
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorFancyCodeGeneratorResult
{
    public class NewAnimatorController
    {
        private static int? _Trigger_SomeTrigger;

        public static int Trigger_SomeTrigger
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Trigger_SomeTrigger == null)
                {
                    _Trigger_SomeTrigger = Animator.StringToHash("Some Trigger");
                }

                return _Trigger_SomeTrigger.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Trigger_AnotherTrigger;

        public static int Trigger_AnotherTrigger
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Trigger_AnotherTrigger == null)
                {
                    _Trigger_AnotherTrigger = Animator.StringToHash("Another Trigger");
                }

                return _Trigger_AnotherTrigger.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Bool_BoolFlag;

        public static int Bool_BoolFlag
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Bool_BoolFlag == null)
                {
                    _Bool_BoolFlag = Animator.StringToHash("Bool Flag");
                }

                return _Bool_BoolFlag.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Bool_OtherBoolFlag;

        public static int Bool_OtherBoolFlag
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Bool_OtherBoolFlag == null)
                {
                    _Bool_OtherBoolFlag = Animator.StringToHash("Other Bool Flag");
                }

                return _Bool_OtherBoolFlag.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Int_SomeInt;

        public static int Int_SomeInt
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Int_SomeInt == null)
                {
                    _Int_SomeInt = Animator.StringToHash("Some Int");
                }

                return _Int_SomeInt.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Int_OtherInt;

        public static int Int_OtherInt
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Int_OtherInt == null)
                {
                    _Int_OtherInt = Animator.StringToHash("Other Int");
                }

                return _Int_OtherInt.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Float_NiceFloat;

        public static int Float_NiceFloat
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Float_NiceFloat == null)
                {
                    _Float_NiceFloat = Animator.StringToHash("Nice Float");
                }

                return _Float_NiceFloat.Value;
            }
        }

        private static int? _Float_OtherFloat;

        public static int Float_OtherFloat
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Float_OtherFloat == null)
                {
                    _Float_OtherFloat = Animator.StringToHash("Other Float");
                }

                return _Float_OtherFloat.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(of course name conflicts might be an issue currently - as said far away from being perfect) and you could later e.g. do

```csharp
animator.SetTrigger(AnimatorFancyCodeGeneratorResult.NewAnimatorController.Trigger_SomeTrigger);
```

This way you will get actual compiler errors if parameters are renamed/removed/retyped etc

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed response!
When I was initially posting the question, I thought I might be missing out on something simple, but I now see it's not that simple. Having said that, it does seem like your solution could be a solid middle ground. I appreciate the help, and I'm sure someone else could find this useful too :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are none. They are not variables which can be accessed in the normal `var_of_type.name_of_prop_or_var` manner. There is an abstraction layer that translates the string to a mapped property that is the actual trigger. If you worked with the AudioMixer, the variables exposing audio properties (such as the volume, for instance) works the same way.

While you could probably make a centralized relationship, such as a Dictionary to map your own name of a property to an internal animator property, the result would still be a string. The difference is it being centralized, one change when populating the dictionary would not impact the code that uses the key, not the value. Still the problem remains that while the code would have less risk, the Animator would still use its own parameter list and thus, you'd need to change it there too.

Still, I don't want to close this answer with a basic "no" without addressing your concerns. You mentioned you are worried that errors would occur either at runtime or on production.

Controlled runtime sessions such as unit tests or full-on testing are meant exactly for this. When playtesting, if your QA team performs proper testing (end-to-end testing, A/B testing and last, but not least, regression testing) they should be able to spot any inconsistencies in code where such problems would occur and in my opinion, it's encouraged as that is one of the point of testing. And if testing is done correctly, the chances of it happening on a final production release are slim.

So for short: while there is no way to automatically check this at build-time, I wouldn't worry about errors during testing, as long as testing follows proper guidelines. However, consider that if you feel the need to change the parameter names too often, there might be a different problem, either in consistency, design or any other area that impacts your development and I'd address that first.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you can miss while testing because it will break your game's animation behaviour and you will see errors if you use a wrong string. Just to make things easier, handle from single place and for optimization purposes i would use [Animator.StringToHash](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.StringToHash.html) function.

```
[SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
    
private const string AnimParam1 = "test1";
private const string AnimParam2 = "test2";
private const string AnimParam3 = "test3";
    
private static readonly int Test1 = Animator.StringToHash(AnimParam1);
private static readonly int Test2 = Animator.StringToHash(AnimParam2);
private static readonly int Test3 = Animator.StringToHash(AnimParam3);

private void Awake()
{
    _animator.SetBool(Test1, true);
    _animator.SetInteger(Test2, 2);
    _animator.SetFloat(Test3, 3.0f);
}
```

You can also use [Animator.parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-parameters.html) at runtime to run some manual checks if you like but i don't think it will worth the effort. If those parameters were also ready at build time then you could definetely use them to your advantage.

Comment: Regarding `Animator.parameters`, I agree it's not worth it. Adding an `#if` for development builds and running checks before executing would be the same as directly executing and having errors. Defensive programming is not always the best course of action, sometimes it's better to let it crash since that's what testing is all about anyway: catching errors (be it exceptions, spelling, scene triggers, app workflows or whatever else).

Comment: Regarding `StringToHash()`, as I said in my other comment, if the string is different, the hash is different so there would be no real difference or gain. While overkill, I'd rather use a Dictionary, although I wouldn't really go that route either, especially if the animations will change very often. But with a dictionary at least the key remains the same and if the same parameter is used someplace else, you'd have the same Dictionary, same key, while the value would be set once. Depends on preference.

Comment: I totally understand your point but i wouldn't consider this as an overkill since it is for optimization purposes because comparing ints is faster than strings and making an optimization into a best practise is totally worth it as long as it doesn't effect the readability of the code.

Comment: Reference to [unity docs about animator usage](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/controlling-animation#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b4e2) with `Animator.StringToHash`

Comment: Of course, this is why I would said it's something I wouldn't really use. Also keep in mind that hash comparing wouldn't really help in this scenario, but it is indeed more efficient to use performance wise. However, it wouldn't change anything in the scenario the OP mentioned. In other scenarios I totally agree with you.